# How can I fopen a disk to write to the last sector in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to open a disk and write to the last sector. On Linux, the code looks like this:

```
char data[] = "end of disk";
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("/dev/sda", "w");
fseek(fp, -4096, SEEK_END);
fwrite((void*) data, 1, sizeof(data), fp);
fclose(fp);
```

I tried using this on windows:

```
char data[] = "end of disk";
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0", "w");
fseek(fp, -4096, SEEK_END);
fwrite((void*) data, 1, sizeof(data), fp);
fclose(fp);
```

However, this seems to fail at `fopen()`. How can I open a disk to write to the last sector in Windows?

Comment: whatever you do use `"wb"` not `"w"`. And did you try that as administrator/elevated privileges?

Comment: you do not want to truncate the disk either...

Comment: yeah, try reading from it first... and make a backup

Comment: You most probably don't want to use stdio for disk accesses

Comment: Also, it might be "permission denied", check `errno`.

Comment: using admin privileges, using `"wb"`. errno says 22, "Invalid argument". maybe it has a problem with `"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"`?